# Is it overkill to encrypt an already hashed BCrypt password?

Tags: mysql, passwords, bcrypt

I'm using BCrypt to hash my passwords on the server side.  Before I store it in my MySQL database, would it be overkill to encrypt my hashed-BCrypt password or would storing the hash directly in the database suffice?

This [website](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) advises to encrypt passwords after hashing them:

> As long as an attacker can use a hash to check whether a password
>   guess is right or wrong, they can run a dictionary or brute-force
>   attack on the hash. The next step is to add a secret key to the hash
>   so that only someone who knows the key can use the hash to validate a
>   password. This can be accomplished two ways. Either the hash can be
>   encrypted using a cipher like AES, or the secret key can be included
>   in the hash using a keyed hash algorithm like HMAC.

EDIT:  I'm coding in Java.  I'm trying to gauge whether the added layer of protection vs. speed performance of read & retrieval of passwords for user logins is worth it or not.

Comment: What do you hope to gain by encrypting it?

Comment: Are you using PHP?

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark I'm trying to gauge whether the added layer of protection vs. the speed performance of retrieving the password to login for users is worth it or not

Comment: @RaymondNijland Java

Comment: If you run the generating bcrypt method on the same password does you get different hashes.. in PHP this is the case meaning the PHP version is safe against bruteforce the hash attack to get the password. Verification happens in PHP with password_verify()  to check if the password is correct.. Not sure how this works in Java because googling gives some different frameworks to use Bcrypt in Java...

Comment: @RaymondNijland Running Bcrypt on the same password will generate different hashes everytime.

Comment: "Running bycrypt on the same password will generate different hashes everytime." Ok great then don't worry about rainbow table "decryption" and bruteforce  attacks then..

Comment: Next question.. Do you have the MySQL username and password in the Java program which is public accessible?

Comment: @RaymonNijland my MySQL database has username and password that is only known by me (dev) and admin (my client).  P.S. - I think continuing our conversation on this thread is a bad idea according to SO guidelines

Comment: On topic questions comments are allowed to ask more information.. Well mine comment isn't totally 100% on topic but still your question is about direction security and mine comment was also in that direction.. So i geuss it's okay  there.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd trust "crackstation" with any password advice. Just use bcrypt and encrypt your entire database at rest. Don't mess around with field-level encryption, you're going to do it wrong anyway and it won't add any additional security. It'll just make managing your database an order of magnitude more complicated than it otherwise would be. If you want more password security, set bcrypt at a higher "difficulty" setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would indeed increase security, but it is good to know what exactly you gain with encryption.

- Encrypting the password-hash can protect weak user passwords from a
  dictionary attack, in the special case, where the attacker has
  read-access to the database (containing the hashes) but does not have
  access to the source code with the key/pepper.

This situation is not so uncommon as one would think, typical scenarios would be SQL-injection, thrown away backups, discarded servers...

To be able to brute-force for passwords one needs the server side key, which was used to encrypt the password-hashes. This means, being able to read the hashes from the database is not enough anymore, one needs additional privileges to read the key from the server. Getting privileges on the server is much more difficult than being able to read the database.

Crackstation is a good site for advice. At the end of my own tutorial about [safely storing password](https://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php) I try to explain the details of this password-hash encryption.